# Angular UI-Routing is not loading my partial into the viewport

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I have a Node.JS+Express backend, and am trying to set up an angular frontend.

I have a basic HTML template called `common.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Watson-Amadeus</title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/index.css" />
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel = "script" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"  />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/amadeus.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app = "watson_amadeus">
            <div ui-view>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`js/amadeus.js` then looks like

```
var app = angular.module("watson_amadeus", ["ui.router"]);
app.config(($stateProvider) => {
    var introState = {
        name: "intro",
        url:  "/intro",
        templateUrl: "../index.html"
    }

var amadeusState = {
    name: "amadeus",
    url:  "/amadeus",
    template: "../watson-amadeus.html"
}

$stateProvider.state(introState);
$stateProvider.state(amadeusState);
});

app.controller("amadeus_controller", ($scope) => {
  $scope.messages = [
                      {text: "Yo"},
                      {text: "sup?"}
                    ];
  console.log("controller");
  $scope.send_message = () => {
      $scope.messages.push({text: $scope.msg_to_send});
      $scope.msg_to_send = "";
  };
});
```

`intro.html` and `watson-amadeus.html` are then just partials with some html in them.  My Node server code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
amadeus = require('./rest/amadeus.js'),
body_parser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(body_parser.json());
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static("public"));  // Use static pages from the public directory

app.post("/api/amadeus/", amadeus.send_message);
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/common.html");
});

app.listen(8080);  // Set the server to listen on port 8080
```

Finally, my directory structure is reasonably straightforward:

```
project_dir

  public

    js

      amadeus.js

    common.html
    index.html
    watson-amadeus.html

  node_server.js
  package.json
```

When I start the web server and try `http://localhost:8080/intro`, I am greeted with just a blank screen, and looking at the page source shows that it is just loading `common.html` without putting the `index.html` content into the viewport as it should.  What is more; when I do `http://localhost:8080/`, I get the contents of index.html, but without the parts from common.html.

I'm new to angular, so this may be something fundamental but I don't know where I have messed up.

Comment: amadeusState are using template instead of templateUrl like in index try changeit.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once you defined `app.use(express.static('public'));`, express server will load index.html automatically, so `app.get("*", (req, res) => {  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/common.html"); });` won't run at all.

I would recommend rename `common.html` to `index.html` since it is your major html.

2. By default `ui-route` will add`#!` to url, try `http://10.8.8.8:8080/`, after `index.html` has been loaded successfully, the url actually changed to `http://10.8.8.8:8080/#!/`.
   Hence, you can access your `/intro` by `http://10.8.8.8:8080/#!/intro`.

There will be lots of effort to take if you want to remove `#!`, you can research next step. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the #! thing, and thanks for the advice with the renaming!  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yep, popping the #! in the url worked!  Now I've got to work out how to get rid of it.  But at least I know what the issue is.  Many thanks!